# How to launch an app by dialing a specific number?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i am developing an android application, in which i want application icon to be hidden when toggle button is clicked. I am done with this task, Now i want when a specific code is dialed from launcher then launcher activity should be fired again.
i have implemented this too, but dialer code is unable to let me into the application again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

//Java Code

```
  String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");

         if(phoneNumber.equals("#588637#")) { 
    //do your stuff here
         Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.mycompany.DO_SOMETHING");
    context.startActivity(intent);
         }
```

//Manifest

```
<activity
android:name=".OtherAppActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.mycompany.DO_SOMETHING" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```